# Read data One by one to JTextField from file

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am developing a gui using swing in which i need to read integer values from a text file in JTextField.The text file has only 5 values so i need to make 5 texfields in my gui and input the values one by one in my Jtextfield from the text file. Please help

Comment: I don't know how to do it that is why is asked.please help

Comment: @Ruby dev I understand you don't know how to do this, but SO is not here to write programs. If you don't know where to start, do a search. The official Java tutorials cover everything you mention. I also suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Like every thing in java or just programming there are lots of ways you can do it. For one you can use a scanner to read in the file and then split the values/numbers for example. Say your text file looks like this.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

What you can do is you can read the text file into a string, then all you need to do is to make a string array and use the string split method to take out and split the commas.

```
String[] strArray =  str.split(",");
```

Each value/number is in a different index of the array, for example: if you wanted to get or display the third number you could just do something like this.

```
System.out.println(strArray[2]);
```

The output would be of cause the third number/value in this case it's 3. There are lots of way's to read in and display values. I recommend go reading the documentation on [Scanners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: can u please give me an example of how to do it.Thank You @ReallNandOUT

Comment: Using StringBuffer and then by split i could read file to jtextfield but since i have 3 rows in my text file i was able to read only the 1st row.can u please tell me how to do it.@ReallNandOUT

Comment: There are many ways to read in a text file just like everything in Java. The way I normally would go about reading in a text file is to use the scanner class that can read line by line in a while loop and then after the scanner has read in a line you add the line to a string and this while loop will keep doing this until all lines a read in. Sorry about really late reply I've been busy. P.S the while loop should be checking if the next line is null or not, if a line comes back null it means the line is the end of the file.